# Setting timeout for Appcelerator Cloud API call

Tags: cloud, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium Mobile framework to develop an app for iPhone.

I'm facing a problem regarding setting timeout for ACS(Appcelerator Cloud Service) API call, so that if network is not strong enough, the app don't hang.

How can I do this. I read the documentation but couldn't locate something related to this.

Following is my code.

```
Cloud.Objects.query({
        classname: 'MyScores',
        page: 2,
        per_page: 5,
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {

        }
        else {

        }
    });
```